# How synonyms work internally in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I came across with Elasticsearch some time ago and started exploring it. I got to know about `synonyms feature` which is amazing! Can someone explain how internally this whole synonyms process work? How index time synonyms analyzing and search time synonyms analyzing are different in terms of internal structure?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Doc:

> Typically, the same parser should be applied at both index time and
> lookup time to ensure that the query terms are in the same format as
> the inverted index terms.

When you use the search_analyzer synonyms, you are generating the synonym tokens for the search term just in search time.

When you use synonyms at indexing time, you are expanding the term to the other terms of the synonyms, that is, everything is there in the inverted index. This can decrease your storage as you are indexing more term.

IndexTime example:

```
PUT synonym_index_time
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "synonyms_filter"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "synonyms_filter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "lenient": true,
            "synonyms": [
              "laptop, notebook"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Test:

```
GET synonym_index_time/_analyze
{
  "field": "name",
  "text": ["laptop"]
}
```

Results:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "laptop",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "notebook",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Look, the terms laptop and notebook have been indexed, but notebook is a synonym.

Comment: So, Let's say we have one document indexed { "name" : "I have a laptop" }. And we query it with "I have a notebook", which will be a match. So at backend, the query is tokenized. Then it finds synonyms from inverted index for each token and do the necessary matching and scoring for all possible results/documents from the index. Am I right?

Comment: Correct. A nice way to see how matches are done field by field is to enable "explain:true". This way you will see that for the term laptop and elastic you will use the synonyms feature to calculate the score. It will be something like this: "weight(Synonym(name:laptop name:notebook) in 0)"

Comment: Ohhkay. Thanks man. It helped. ;)